# Moving elements from one array to another. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list

So basically I have a Grocery List and an Inventory List. I want to be able to:

1. Add an item to either list.
2. Remove an item from either list.
3. Move an item from one list to the other.

Each list has its own array, and when you "Add an item" to either list, I have a function (nodeConstructor) that pushes the item to its corresponding array and builds an 'item element' in the desired div (the grocery list or inventory list).

The problem that I'm having is in moving an item from one list to the other. When you click the 'move' button, my 'nodeConstructor' function is supposed to be called and it should basically recreate the selected element in the other list. It kind of does that, except the item value (inputVal) renders as 'undefined' in the div rather than the value of the item that was moved (however it moves from array to array correctly).

The other problem is that moving an item from the Grocery List to the Inventory List correctly splices the item from the Grocery List array and pushes it to the Inventory List array, but moving an item from the Inventory List to the Grocery List neither splices the item from the array nor moves it to the Grocery List array (I'm thinking it has something to do with the order of conditionals being checked but I'm not sure).

If anyone could show me where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Also, any suggestions on an easier way to achieve this functionality would be welcomed.

Here is a link to the Codepen that demonstrates my issue: https://codepen.io/TOOTCODER/pen/OJXQKGp?editors=1011

HTML

```
<label for="groceryInput">Add Grocery Item: </label>
<input id="groceryInput" type="text">
<button id="groceryInputBtn">Submit</button>

<label for="inventoryInput">Add Inventory Item: </label>
<input id="inventoryInput" type="text">
<input id="inventoryInputBtn" type="submit">

<div class="outputDiv" id="arr1Output"><h1>Grocery</h1></div>
<div class="outputDiv" id="arr2Output"><h1>Inventory</h1></div>
```

CSS

```
.outputDiv{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
}

.outputDiv h1{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const groceryInput = document.querySelector("#groceryInput");
const groceryInputBtn = document.querySelector("#groceryInputBtn");
const inventoryInput = document.querySelector("#inventoryInput");
const inventoryInputBtn = document.querySelector("#inventoryInputBtn");
const arr1Output = document.querySelector("#arr1Output");
const arr2Output = document.querySelector("#arr2Output");
const groceryList = [];
const inventoryList = [];

//add grocery item
groceryInputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  nodeConstructor(groceryInput, groceryList, arr1Output, "newGroceryItemDiv", "newGroceryItem", "groceryDeleteBtnSpan", "groceryMoveBtnSpan")});

 arr1Output.addEventListener("click", controlBtns);

//add inventory item
inventoryInputBtn.addEventListener("click",  function(){
  nodeConstructor(inventoryInput, inventoryList, arr2Output, "newInventoryItemDiv", 
  "newInventoryItem", "inventoryDeleteBtnSpan", "inventoryMoveBtnSpan")});

   arr2Output.addEventListener("click", controlBtns);

//item element builder
function nodeConstructor(inputVal, list, output, divClass,itmClass, deleteClass, moveClass){
  const newItmDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newItmDiv.classList.add(divClass);
  const newItm = document.createElement("span");
  newItm.classList.add("itmClass");
  const deleteBtnSpan = document.createElement("span");
  deleteBtnSpan.innerHTML = "<i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>";
  deleteBtnSpan.classList.add(deleteClass);
  const moveBtnSpan = document.createElement("span");
  moveBtnSpan.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-exchange-alt'></i>";
  moveBtnSpan.classList.add(moveClass);
  
  list.push(inputVal.value);
  
  for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    newItm.innerText = list[i];
    }
  
  newItmDiv.appendChild(newItm);
  newItmDiv.appendChild(deleteBtnSpan);
  newItmDiv.appendChild(moveBtnSpan);
  output.appendChild(newItmDiv);
};


//delete and move buttons
function controlBtns(event){
  const clicked = event.target;
  for(let i=0;i<groceryList.length;i++){
    //grocery delete btn
    if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==groceryList[i] && 
       clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="groceryDeleteBtnSpan"){
       groceryList.splice(i,1);
       clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
    //grocery move btn
    if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==groceryList[i] && 
       clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="groceryMoveBtnSpan"){
      nodeConstructor(groceryList[i], inventoryList, arr2Output, "newInventoryItemDiv", "newInventoryItem", "inventoryDeleteBtnSpan", "inventoryMoveBtnSpan");
       inventoryList.push(groceryList[i]);
       groceryList.splice(i,1);
       clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
      
      //inventory delete btn
    for(let i=0;i<inventoryList.length;i++){
      if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==inventoryList[i] && 
       clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="inventoryDeleteBtnSpan"){
       inventoryList.splice(i,1);
       clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
      //inventory move btn
      if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.value==inventoryList[i] && 
       clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="inventoryMoveBtnSpan"){
        nodeConstructor(inventoryList[i], groceryList, arr1Output, "newGroceryItemDiv", "newGroceryItem", "groceryDeleteBtnSpan", "groceryMoveBtnSpan");
       groceryList.push(inventoryList[i]);
       inventoryList.splice(i,1);
       clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
  console.log("InventoryList: "+inventoryList);
  console.log("GroceryList: "+groceryList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey so the below code will at least work with the switching, the issue you had is you were not calling the `nodeConstructor` in the move button and since your lists only contain the value, nothing was being updated.

So what I did was updated `nodeConstructor` to take both input value and value of the item you are moving with this line `const nodeValue = typeof inputVal === 'object' ? inputVal.value : inputVal`

Then in the move functions I updated both move functions. I grabbed the old value before I delete it from the list, then I call the `nodeContructor` so both the lists are updated with the value.

```
const groceryVal = groceryList[i]
      groceryList.splice(i,1);
             nodeConstructor(groceryVal, inventoryList, arr2Output, "newInventoryItemDiv", "newInventoryItem", "inventoryDeleteBtnSpan", "inventoryMoveBtnSpan");
      clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
```

In terms of of what you could be doing. I think you could probably add a click event to the move buttons that update their own position so you dont have to have that big function.

```js
const groceryInput = document.querySelector("#groceryInput");
    const groceryInputBtn = document.querySelector("#groceryInputBtn");
    const arr1Output = document.querySelector("#arr1Output");

    const inventoryInput = document.querySelector("#inventoryInput");
    const inventoryInputBtn = document.querySelector("#inventoryInputBtn");
    const arr2Output = document.querySelector("#arr2Output");
    const groceryList = [];
    const inventoryList = [];
    let nodeList = [];
    groceryInputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      nodeConstructor(groceryInput, groceryList, arr1Output, "newGroceryItemDiv", "newGroceryItem", "groceryDeleteBtnSpan", "groceryMoveBtnSpan");
    });

    arr1Output.addEventListener("click", controlBtns);

    inventoryInputBtn.addEventListener("click",  function(){
      nodeConstructor(inventoryInput, inventoryList, arr2Output, "newInventoryItemDiv", "newInventoryItem", "inventoryDeleteBtnSpan", "inventoryMoveBtnSpan");
    });
    arr2Output.addEventListener("click", controlBtns);


    function nodeConstructor(inputVal, list, output, divClass,itmClass, deleteClass, moveClass){
      const newItmDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newItmDiv.classList.add(divClass);
      const newItm = document.createElement("span");
      newItm.classList.add("itmClass");
      const deleteBtnSpan = document.createElement("span");
      deleteBtnSpan.innerHTML = "<i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>";
      deleteBtnSpan.classList.add(deleteClass);
      const moveBtnSpan = document.createElement("span");
      moveBtnSpan.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-exchange-alt'></i>";
      moveBtnSpan.classList.add(moveClass);
      
      const nodeValue = typeof inputVal === 'object' ? inputVal.value :
      inputVal
      list.push(nodeValue);
      
      for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        newItm.innerText = list[i];
        }
      newItmDiv.appendChild(newItm);
      newItmDiv.appendChild(deleteBtnSpan);
      newItmDiv.appendChild(moveBtnSpan);
      output.appendChild(newItmDiv);
    };


    function controlBtns(event){
      const clicked = event.target;
      for(let i=0;i<groceryList.length;i++){
        //groceryDeleteBtn
        if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==groceryList[i] && 
           clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="groceryDeleteBtnSpan"){
          groceryList.splice(i,1);
          clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
        //groceryMoveBtn
        if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==groceryList[i] && 
           clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="groceryMoveBtnSpan"){
          const groceryVal = groceryList[i]
          groceryList.splice(i,1);
                 nodeConstructor(groceryVal, inventoryList, arr2Output, "newInventoryItemDiv", "newInventoryItem", "inventoryDeleteBtnSpan", "inventoryMoveBtnSpan");
          clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
     
        }
      }
      
      for(let i=0;i<inventoryList.length;i++){
        //inventoryDeleteBtn
        if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==inventoryList[i] && 
           clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="inventoryDeleteBtnSpan"){
          inventoryList.splice(i,1);
          clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
        //inventoryMoveBtn
        if(clicked.parentElement.parentElement.innerText==inventoryList[i] && clicked.parentElement.classList[0]=="inventoryMoveBtnSpan"){
          const inventoryVal= inventoryList[i]
          inventoryList.splice(i,1);
             nodeConstructor(inventoryVal, groceryList, arr1Output, "newGroceryItemDiv", "newGroceryItem", "groceryDeleteBtnSpan", "groceryMoveBtnSpan");
          clicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            
        }
      }
      console.log("InventoryList: "+inventoryList);
      console.log("GroceryList: "+groceryList);
    }
```